# Convergence of integral on every measurable subset

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{f_n\}$ be sequence in $L^2[0,1]$ and $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function such that for every Lebesgue measurable set $E$ in $[0,1]$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E}f_n dx = \int_{E}fdx$. Assume also that $\sup_{n}\int_{0}^{1} \lvert f_n \rvert^2 dx < \infty$. I want to show that $f \in L^2[0,1]$.

My thought so far: If we manage to show there is a subsequence of $f_n$ converging pointwise a.e. on $[0,1]$ to $f$, we're done. Indeed, if this is true, then by Fatou's lemma, we have $$\int_{0}^{1} \lvert f \rvert^2 dx \leqslant \liminf \int_{0}^{1} \lvert f_{n_k}\rvert^2 dx \leqslant \sup_{n}\int_{0}^{1} \lvert f_n \rvert^2 dx < \infty$$ But I don't know how to achieve that. I tried to show $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ or in measure but I failed. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: For $\epsilon>0$ you can find a subsequence $\{f_{s(\epsilon, n)}\}$ such that $\mu(\{x:|f_{s(n)}(x)-f(x)|<1/n\})<\epsilon 2^{-n}$ so you get pointwise convergence outside of this $\epsilon$-sized set, if I'm not mistaken?  Not sure if it helps, though...

Comment: Ah, using diagonalization you get a a.e. convergent subsequence from this I think, but maybe there are easier ways...

Comment: @fweth Why? We don't have $L^1$ convergence. We only have the convergence of integrals.

Comment: @Feng ah yes, you are right, forget what I wrote...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the assumption that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E}f_n dx =\int_{E}fdx$ for all measurable sets $E\subset[0,1]$, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1f_n \varphi \,dx = \int_0^1f\varphi \,dx,$$
for all simple functions $\varphi$ on $[0,1]$. Since $C^2:=\sup_{n}\int_{0}^{1} \lvert f_n \rvert^2 dx < \infty$, by Cauchy-Schwartz we have
$$\left|\int_0^1f_n\varphi \,dx\right|\leq C\|\varphi\|_{L^2}\Longrightarrow\left|\int_0^1f\varphi \,dx\right|\leq C\|\varphi\|_{L^2},\ \ \ \text{for all simple functions }\varphi.\tag{$*$}$$
Now it follows from duality that $f\in L^2$.

Here in the last step we used [Theorem 6.14 in Folland's Real Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=wI4fAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PT148#v=onepage&q&f=false). Here is a (simplified) proof from Folland that $(*)$ implies $f\in L^2$: Let $\phi_n$ be a sequence of simple functions such that $\phi_n\to f$ a.e. and $|\phi_n|\leq|f|$, and let
$$\varphi_n=\frac{|\phi_n|\mathrm{sgn}f}{\|\phi_n\|_{L^2}}.$$
Then $\varphi_n$ is a sequence of simple functions with $\|\varphi_n\|_{L^2}=1$. By Fatou's lemma and all these definitions we have
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{L^2}&\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\|\phi_n\|_{L^2}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 |\varphi_n\phi_n|\,dx\\
&\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 |\varphi_nf|\,dx=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \varphi_nf\,dx\\
&\stackrel{(*)}{\leq} C\|\varphi_n\|_{L^2}=C<\infty.
\end{align*}